# Visualizar variables en vscode

Tags: python, vscode

Estoy empezando a programar en python en vscode (vengo de Matlab), y estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de visualizar variables.

Cuando hablamos de matrices pequeñas, es muy fácil con un print y poco más, pero cuando ya tiene dimensiones mas grandes me es algo atareado y difícil.

Me preguntaba si hay alguna extensión o algún ajuste que permita ver todas las variables que tengo de un script y sus respectivos valores, dimensiones etc.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: aparte de lo comentado abajo puedes usar el [jupyter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estás con VSCode, lo más fácil en mi opinión es utilizar el modo de depuración (debug). Cuando pausas el script en algún punto, el programa te muestra todas las variables definidas en ese momento (su valor, su tipo...) e incluso puedes imprimirlas en la consola de depuración.

Para activar el modo debug, simplemente añade un break point (el puntito rojo) pulsando a la izquierda del número de línea en cualquier punto del programa y en lugar de ejecutar el script selecciona "Depurar archivo de python".

Answer (score 1):

Yo quitaría la duda de si hay una extensión, ya que no damos recomendaciones de recursos externos.

Si, existe algo. Teniendo en cuenta lo siguiente:

- La librería estandar incluye un módulo llamado [pprint](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/pprint.html) con una función homonima, que nos permite imprimir recursivamente de forma más entendible los objetos.
- Podemos obtener las variables del ambito actual en forma de diccionario usando `vars()`.
- `vars()` no incluye las variables globales, por lo que podemos obtenerlas con `globals()`

Por lo tanto, podemos usar el siguiente código para obtener todas las variables accesibles desde la función.

```
from pprint import pprint

pprint(globals() | vars())
```

**A tener en cuenta**

- El orden en el que se concatenan los diccionarios importa. La intención al hacer esta concatenación es imitar la mecanica de Python de que si una variable local se llama igual que una global, se accede a la variable local por que es "la más cercana".
- Si colocás este código en una función aparte, vars() va a devolver el ámbito de dicha. En ese caso, tendrás que importar el módulo estandar [inspect](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/inspect.html) (encargado de analizar objetos en runtime) y reemplazar vars() por `inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals`, que devolverá las variables locales del ambito afuera de la función.
- si hay algo muy grande a la hora de imprimir, tu consola va a llenarse de mucho texto. Ten en cuenta que el vscode muestra las ultimas n lineas (no conozco el valor de n, pero me pasó que no muestra todo).
- pprint no da toda la información adicional mencionada en la pregunta, como las dimensiones de una lista. En ese caso, tendrás que buscar otra cosa o crear tu propia versión de pprint (quizá basandote en el código de dicho)